# How to prevent insert in distinct 2 columns combination in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id | FirstName | lastName | age 
--------------------------------
```

But when I inserted some data my table that looks like this.

```
id | FirstName | lastName | age 
--------------------------------
01 | praneeth  | madusanka| 22
02 | praneeth  | praneeth | 23
03 | madusanka | praneeth | 25
04 | praneeth  | madusanka| 33
05 | damith    | asanka   | 43
06 | damith    | danushka | 22
07 | damith    | asanka   | 33
08 |asanka     | damith   | 44
```

But I wont to prevent id=04 data. Because id=01 and id=04 is same data. How I create insert query for preventing above data, for inserting my table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create composite key (FirstName + Lastname)

> If a primary key consists of two or more columns it is called a
>   composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique key with columns firstname and lastname. This would prevent duplicate combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`FirstName`, `lastName`);